# Insert into a junction table in SQLite

Tags: sqlite, junction

I have tried various ways. This is the one that makes sense to me, however when I try to execute the `insert into listsandplayers`, it tells me no column `listID` exists. I tried a couple of different things with my `insert into listsandplayers` statement and continued to get that error.

I have posted here how I feel the statement should work best. It is the last statement shown here.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS 
   lists (listID INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, listName VARCHAR(30));

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS 
   players(playerID INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, playerName VARCHAR);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS 
    listsandplayers(listsandplayersID INTEGER NOT NULL, 
                    listID INTEGER REFERENCES lists (listID),  
                    playerID INTEGER REFERENCES players (playerID));

INSERT INTO lists (listName) VALUES('Los Angeles Dodgers');

INSERT INTO players (playerName) VALUES('Clayton Kershaw');

INSERT INTO listsandplayers (listID, playerID) VALUES(listID, playerID)   
WHERE listName = 'Los Angeles Dodgers'  
AND playerName = 'Clayton Kershaw'  
NATURAL JOIN lists  
NATURAL JOIN players;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not [valid syntax for an `INSERT` command](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_insert.html).
Try this:

```
INSERT INTO ListsAndPlayers (ListsAndPlayersID, ListID, PlayerID)
VALUES (42,
        (SELECT ListID FROM Lists WHERE ListName = 'Los Angeles Dodgers'),
        (SELECT PlayerID FROM Players WHERE PlayerName = 'Clayton Kershaw'));
```

If you had declared the `ListsAndPlayersID` column as `INTEGER PRIMARY KEY`, SQLite would automatically generate a value.
(You could also drop the `ListsAndPlayersID` column and just use the combination of `ListID` and `PlayerID` as primary key.)

Comment: yea Im sorry, i cant believe that i didnt define the listsandplayersID as a primary.  thanks.  i also would never have used select statements for the values, i was thinking joins.